# .htaccess rewrites with some issues

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have some problem with my current htaccess file (rewrites) and it would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me out with this.

Here is my current htaccess file:

```
     Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -indexes
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     # remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
     RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
     # remove index
     RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]
     # remove slash if not directory
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
     RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]
     # add .php to access file, but don't redirect
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
     RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]        
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+sections/([^\s]+) [NC]
     RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule (?!^sections/)^(.*)$ /sections/$1 [L,NC]
```

In my public_html folder I have a sub-folder called sections, which by itself contains several other sub-folders. What I am looking to achieve is to actually hide the /sections/ folder which works to a certain extend using the configuration I have posted above, however I am still experiencing a few issues.

If I am to open **www.mydomain.com/sections/file** it successfully redirects to **www.mydomain.com/file** - this is already good, however if I try to add the .php extension (just for testing purposes) the redirect works (sections folder is being skipped), however the file-extension is not trimmed (I still see .php) which should be removed and I see a page with the text **Moved Permanently - The document has moved here...**

Is there anything I can do / modify in my current .htaccess file or something that is not correct? Some expert advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Update as per requested:

```
     DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
     Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -indexes
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /

     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+sub/(.+?)\.php [NC]
     RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

     # remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
     RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301]

     # remove index
     RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=302]
     # remove slash if not directory
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
     RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301,L]

     # add .php to access file, but don't redirect
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
     RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule (?!^sections/)^(.*)$ /sections/$1 [L,NC]

     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "xxx"
     AuthUserFile "/home/xxx/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
     require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete .htaccess:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -indexes
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+sections/(.+?)(?:\.php)?[/?\s] [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

 # remove index
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)?[\s?/] [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)index(/|$) /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

 # remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
 RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301]

 # remove index
 RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=302]
 # remove slash if not directory
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
 RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301,L]

 # add .php to access file, but don't redirect
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
 RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule (?!^sections/)^(.+)$ /sections/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava , I've tried your suggestion to replace it with the code you've lined out, however with the same result as before.

Comment: Interesting enough I think there is something else going on as I can't open the main domain e.g. domain.com which ends up with an error stating "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /sections/ on this server." , it works though if I manually add /index .. any ideas?

Comment: Yes, with the same Forbidden You don't have permission to access /sections/ on this server error

Comment: Ok try adding `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` line on top of .htaccess.
`

Comment: As soon as I am to remove the last 4 lines of the code I have posted in my initial post everything works fine, meaning the domain.com works, and all extensions are trimmed so there is definitely something wrong with the /sections/ rewrite part

Comment: Do you have .htaccess in `/sections/` also?

Comment: No, I don't, only in the main public_html folder

Comment: I provided you complete .htaccess, try it now.

Comment: WOW that is great anubhava - thank you so much. Unfortunately it seems that it's still not working :( /sections/ is not being skipped and mydomain.com still shows up the error as posted before , it only works if I manually add .com/index - the thing that does work now though is the removal of the .php extensions.

Comment: With latest updated answer everything worked fine for me. You need to try in a different browser to test it. Also tell me which full URL didn't work for you?

Comment: Hello again and thank you very much for all your effort - so much appreciated. I've tested it in different browsers with the same result. www.domain.com ends up showing the "Forbidden 
You don't have permission to access /sections/ on this server" error. If I add index though it works. If I open an url out of sections e.g. domain.com/sections/file or file.php the extension will be trimmed (works fine) however /sections/ does not rewrite - the URL remains domain/com/sections/file

Comment: Do you still have `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` line on top?

Comment: Hello again. Tried to add it now - cleared cache in several browsers to retest but always the same Forbidden error and /sections/ won't rewrite

Comment: Ok post your complete ..htaccess again in the question.

Comment: I have updated my first post - and thanks again for all the effort Mr. anubhava

Comment: For testing replace `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -indexes` with `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` and see the behavior.

Comment: By removing -indexes /sections/ did still not rewrite, strangely enough though when I opened mydomain.com I saw the full directly index of the /sections/ folder, so mydomain.com showed me everything that is in /sections/ even though I did not open mydomain.com/sections/

Comment: Do you not have a `/section/index.php` file?

Comment: Hello Mr. anubhava. No, I don't. /sections/ only contains individual files and subfolders, neither of those contain any index file.

Comment: Well that explains the problem. You need to have a default file like `index.php`. Otherwise if you disable listing using `-indexes` then forbidden error is expected for `/sections/`

Comment: WOW - this indeed seems to work - thank you so much!!! I can open mydomain.com and it works absolutely fine. All file extensions are trimmed as well if I am to add .php for testing purposes. There is still though an issue with the sections part. I am able to open .com/sections/file and I am able to open the same file through .com/file , basically it's now available "twice". Is there a way to completely redirect this?

Comment: try updated code now and make sure to clear browser cache for testing.

Comment: YESSS !!! This works - you are an absolute life-saver Mr. anubhava, thank you so very very much, you are a real expert. Extensions are trimmed, sections redirects properly! I have made several tests and everything works fine, with the exception now that .com/index still works , so /index is not being removed if I type it in manually

Comment: Thank you Mr. anubhava - do you think there is any other way that I can have the index removed? That's really the last thing I need other than that all works absolutely perfect!

Comment: You are a true superhero Mr. Anubhava, everything is just fantastic now. I wouldn't have know what I have done without you! Thank you again , very very much for all the extensive help you have provided for this!